# createJS coordinates mismatch with canvas

Tags: canvas, easeljs

I have a canvas with 1280px width and 800px height. When I create a text object and set the coordinates to x:100 and y:100; it shows the text as shown in the picture. [in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVjmY.png)

Do x and y value not have the pixel unit? If not, how can I change it to pixel?

Comment: As is obvious from the size and blurriness of the text, the canvas has much smaller internal dimensions (the default is 300x150). You need to also set `context.width` to 1200 and `context.height` to 800, not just the `<canvas>` element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added CSS to modify the canvas; where I set the values for width and height. It seems that the correct usage was

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1280px" height="800px"></canvas>

after all. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML canvas element has its own width and height:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
```

Which you can also change in JavaScript:

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
can.width = 500; // the default is 300
can.height = 500; // the default is 150
```

This is *separate* from the CSS width and height of the canvas. This line sets them both:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="width:300px; height:500px"></canvas>
```

Try setting both and see if you get what you want. It is possible that you only set the CSS, and did not set the `canvas.width` and `height` which are still the small default values of `300` and `150`!

On high density displays, many apps set a `canvas.width` and `height` to some value (say 100) and the CSS number to be half that (50). They do this to make the canvas more pixel dense. If this sounds like what you need, you'll want to read about "canvas pixel density."